# Why is '{' not accepted in this regular expression?

Tags: java, regex

When I try to convert this "( |{|;)" regular expression to string, Java gives me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 2
( |{|;)
  ^
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: By enclosing the `{` with `[` and `]`: `[{]`. If you need to match a space, or a brace or a `;`, add them all into the character class: `[ {;]`

Comment: seeing the expression itself would be as usefull as seeing the stacktrace

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is with the `{` that is treated as a beginning of a limiting quantifier (e.g. `{1,2}`). You need to either escape it or use inside a character class.

Judging by the regex you have - `( |{|;)` - the problem is with the special regex character handling. Since you want to match either a space, or an opening brace, or a semi-colon, it is advisable to use a character class rather than an alternation group.

So, use

```
([ {;])
```

A character class is a better solution that alternations because it involves much less backtracking.

Comment: I guess you are splitting, otherwise, remove the round brackets (capturing group).